# Regression clustering

Tags: clustering, data-mining, optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-regression

I am looking for references about classical methods in regression clustering.

My problem is the following:

I have a cloud of points that are assumed to have been generated by inverse functions with different coefficients. So that I have a family of regression functions. I only know the form of the model and i don't know the number of clusters.

I would like to implement an algorithm for best fit using n regression functions of same form the inverse function $y = \frac{c}{x}$ with $c$ some constant.

Do you know most popular methodologies? Do you know methods especially suited for this type of regression functions family?

Comment: It does not entirely answer your question but you may want to take a look at mixture models. A downside being that it typically expects a number of clusters (but I have seen people circumvent this by testing multiple number of clusters and keeping the one with the best fit)